# What does ? in tensor shape?

Tags: tensorflow

When I print tensor shapes for the following variables,

```
self.tensor_image = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name('TfPoseEstimator/image:0')
self.tensor_output = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name('TfPoseEstimator/Openpose/concat_stage7:0')
self.tensor_heatMat = self.tensor_output[:, :, :, :19]
self.tensor_pafMat = self.tensor_output[:, :, :, 19:]

self.tensor_output has (?, ?, ?, 57)
self.tensor_heatMat has (?, ?, ?, 19)
self.tensor_pafMat  has (?, ?, ?, 38)
```

What does those `?` mean?

Comment: In means the sizes of those dimensions are indeterminate, and they depend on the inputs you give when you evaluate the tensor.

Comment: If i know input dimension, for example (3,360,480), how to know those ? dimensions?

Comment: I mean in general unless the input placeholders are defined with static dimensions, the only automatic way to determine it is to actually evaluate the tensors with some input of the desired size and check the shape of the resulting value. The other option of course is to just reason about the operations that you have in the graph and try to figure out what should be the output shape.